# Update ProductVersion field in msi or exe files without rebuilding them

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, exe

I'm using VS2010 to build some .sln files. The output of the build is made of .exe and .msi files. Let's say that after build all packages have "142011" as Product Version

When I deliver the packages I need to update the product version property of the .exe and .msi files so that they will use a "release version". Let's say 142099. 
Since I already have all the .exe and .msi files built, i dont' need to re-build them. 
The question is how to update the ReleaseVersion property with the release version without rebuilding them.

Note : Since this is a corporate environment I'm not allowed to use third party software.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a "release branch" in your source control tool and a release build.  You merge your code to the release branch so that it's the same version and then you rebuild the source tree using the desired version #.

Comment: I cannot change the existing logic (adding new branches). And I want to avoid rebuilding all the sources.